# Login with navigation in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a workarea with a side navigation and a header bar. But if the user is not logged in, I want to direct them to the login page.

The main component is as follows

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <Router history={history}>
                  <div>
                      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Reporter}/>
                  </div>
              </Router>
          </Provider>   
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

The Reporter component looks like this:

```
class Reporter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                  <div className="reporter-container">
                      <SideNav/> 
                      <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/reporter" component={WorkArea}/>
                            <Route exact path="/reporter/page1" component={Page1}/>
                            <Route exact path="/reporter/page2" component={Page2}/>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={WorkArea}/>
                      </Switch>    
                  </div>
             </Router>  
        );
      }
    }

export default Reporter;
```

In both examples, I have included react-router-dom and history:

```
import { Switch, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from '../utils/history'
```

SideNav looks like this:

```
class SideNav extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="side-nav">
                <div className="side-nav-item">
                    <i className="fas fa-file side-nav-icon"></i><Link to="/reporter/page1">Page1</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="side-nav-item">
                    <i className="fas fa-male  side-nav-icon"></i><Link to="/reporter/page2">Page2</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default SideNav;
```

The login works fine, but the when I select a side navigation, the URL is going to /reporter/page1, but it is just bank. I think this is because it is looking in the App component routing and finding nothing. I suppose I could move everything to the App component and set the visibility of the side nav bar to none. Does anyone know of the best practice for this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have two routers, the best practice is to handle all of your routing in a single place. Your code is not working because the router can't find the appropriate component to render for the `reporter/page1' route because it's looking in the first router it finds.

You need to handle all of your routing in a single place. This will also allow you to easily handle the redirection to the `/login` route with the `<Redirect />` component from `react-router-dom`

You can do it like this

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    ...
    redirectIfNotLoggedIn = () => {
        return this.state.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to={'/login'} />
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 {this.redirectIfNotLoggedIn()}
                 <-- Actual component code -->
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```